# Eql command returns an empty array when using two parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I am running the command like this:

```
related_attchments = related_documents.collect{|d| d.attachments.all}.flatten.select{|a| [“a”,“b”].eql?(a.attachment_type)}
```

the above command it is returning empty []

so basically I want to know whether I can use .eql? function with two parameters or not.
Because above statement works fine if i pass in below way:

```
related_attchments = related_documents.collect{|d| d.attachments.all}.flatten.select{|a| "a".eql?(a.attachment_type)}
```

Comment: what is the `related_documents`, what is `attachmets`. we still didn't learned to read thoughts

Answer (score 0):

Use include, like this:

```
related_attchments = related_documents.collect{|d| d.attachments.all}.flatten.select{|a| [“a”,“b”].include?(a.attachment_type)}
```

For your case use `include?` instead of `eql?`

`.eql?` use only one parameter, but on the other hand it can be an array as well. In your case `["a","b"]` is comparing only to `"a"`, or `"b"`, so it will never be equal. If it would be the `["a","b"]`, then it would be equal. So, for your case use `include?` instead of `eql` as it will represent the comparison which you want to achieve.

Comment: Thanks, I am glad it helped you. You can mark it as "answered" if you want, so anybody else who is coming to this question would know that the answer contains information that will lead to the solution to this issue.